# Why are so many Python libraries written in C/C++

Tags: python

In most languages, it's safe to assume libraries are written in the same language, ie. a Java library is usually written in Java.

In Python, that doesn't seem to be the case. Many of the high performance libraries such as `numpy`, `pandas` and more are written in C/C++, and provide Python bindings for convenience. It seems we could call these C/C++ libraries instead of Python libraries.

Why is this?

Comment: Prior to its rise to prominence in web development and data science, Python's primary niches was as a "glue language" for C libraries and applications.  Given Python's relative slowness, writing fast code in C and providing a friendly interface in Python has long been a recommended strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question had the answer buried in it: "Many of the high performance libraries...are written in C/C++."

There are two reasons for calling a low-level language from a language like Python, and performance is one of them. Numpy, for example, achieves a lot of its performance by carefully managing (and reusing) memory, and calling it from Python avoids the garbage collection overheads of writing the same functions in Python.

The other reason to call libraries written in another language is to do things not possible in the source language, such as taking advantage of non-blocking I/O system calls, or using special features of a platform such as vector processing instructions, or GPGPUs.